# failed to resolve : Firebase auth 15.0.0

Tags: android, dependency-injection

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

I don't know but the error only shows the appcompat 28.0.0 won't work.

Comment: Remove the `15.0.0`.

Comment: it builded but still made the appcompat in red underline and says it might give crashes.

Comment: You also need to update your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
this, `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'`

to this, `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'`

and better, update all dependencies to the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

The following dependency is put in by the Firebase Assistant to "Add Firebase Authentication to the App"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

If you remove 15.0.0, and make it

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

that automatically removes Firebase Authentication in the Firebase Assistant, beating the whole purpose. Also if you change to the '...firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0' to the latest version '...firebase-auth:16.1.0:15.0.0', nothing happens to the error, as it is due to the '15.0.0' part.

This is probably a blocker bug from Firebase or Google side, which could be only corrected by them. Hope this catches their attention soon. Otherwise all new developments using this version of Firebase Auth or Database will be stalled. Older versions may be working though.